# UMLPackage.Literals.MODEL throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError error

Tags: java, eclipse-emf, emf, model-based-testing

I would like to get the state machine from .uml file created by papyrus. I am parsing the model.uml file using the code below.

```
    ResourceSet set = new ResourceSetImpl();
set.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap()
    .put(UMLResource.FILE_EXTENSION, UMLResource.Factory.INSTANCE);
set.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap()
    .put(UMLResource.FILE_EXTENSION, UMLResource.Factory.INSTANCE);
Resource.Factory.Registry.INSTANCE.getExtensionToFactoryMap()
    .put(UMLResource.FILE_EXTENSION, UMLResource.Factory.INSTANCE);
Resource res = set.getResource(URI.createFileURI("resources/model.uml"), true);
EcoreUtil.resolveAll(res);
System.out.println(res.getContents().get(0));
```

This code works fine and prints the content. But when I try to cast it to Model class using the code below

```
Model model = (Model) EcoreUtil.getObjectByType(res.getContents(),UMLPackage.Literals.MODEL);
```

It throws this exception,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/uml2/types/TypesPackage
at org.eclipse.uml2.uml.internal.impl.UMLPackageImpl.init(UMLPackageImpl.java:1907)
at org.eclipse.uml2.uml.UMLPackage.<clinit>(UMLPackage.java:83)
at org.eclipse.uml2.uml.UMLPackage$Literals.<clinit>(UMLPackage.java:28779)
at mp.m2bt.BTGenerator.main(BTGenerator.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.uml2.types.TypesPackage
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

I am not sure if I am missing anything. I think the problem is in *UMLPackage.Literals.MODEL*. So, Can anybody help me to fix this issue and get the state machines from the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the jar `org.eclipse.uml2.types` in your classpath. This is why the type  `org.eclipse.uml2.types.TypesPackage` cannot be found.